# Replace text inside brackets with partial value identified in each respective row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a bunch of columns, one of which looks like this:

```
data = {'Product': ['Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C (discontinued in March 2021)', 'Product D', 'Product E (discontinued on 30 April 2004)']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I tried writing a piece of code that iterates through every row of the column, identifies the year in the brackets (where applicable) and replaces the text inside the brackets with the following `'discont. '` + `the year identified`. So for `'Product C'`, it should change it to `Product C (discont. 2021)`.

```
def amend_vals(value):
    pattern = r'\((\d{4})\)'  # Regex pattern to capture the year inside brackets
    match = re.search(pattern, value)
    if match:
        year = match.group(1)
        return re.sub(pattern, '(discont. ' + year + ')', value)
    else:
        return value

df['Product'] = df['Product'].apply(amend_vals)
```

It doesn't seem to work though. Anyone have any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex substitution:

```
df['Product'].str.replace(r'\([^(]+(\d{4})\)', rf'(discont. \1)', regex=True)
```

---

```
0                    Product A
1                    Product B
2    Product C (discont. 2021)
3                    Product D
4    Product E (discont. 2004)
Name: Product, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex with lookarounds:

```
df['Product'] = df['Product'].str.replace(r'(?<=\(discont)[^)]+?(?=\d{4}\))',
                                          '. ', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
                     Product
0                  Product A
1                  Product B
2  Product C (discont. 2021)
3                  Product D
4  Product E (discont. 2004)
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pgtma2/1)

```
(?<=\(discont)  # match "(discont"
[^)]+?          # match anything but ")" (non-greedy)
(?=\d{4}\))     # match "DDDD)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed regexp to capture the whole piece inside the brackets and year inside them at the same time. Year to use in text-substitute and the whole piece to replace it with your new text.

```
def amend_vals(value):
    pattern = r'(\([^\(\)]+(\d{4})\))'  # Regex pattern to capture the year inside brackets
    match = re.search(pattern, value)
    if match:
        year = match.group(2)
        return re.sub(pattern, f'(discont. {year})', value)
    else:
        return value

df['Product'].apply(amend_vals)
```

Output:

```
0                    Product A
1                    Product B
2    Product C (discont. 2021)
3                    Product D
4    Product E (discont. 2004)
Name: Product, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

The two problems are:

1. your regex doesn't match any of the strings, and
2. you don't import your libraries (probably you just forgot to include it, but maybe not!)

#### The regular expression

Your regex is `r'\((\d{4})\)`. This matches a four digit number surrounded on both sides by brackets. This means it will match `(2023)`, but won't match `(discontinued 2023)` or any other number within brackets where there's something else in there with the number.

The obvious answer is to modify it so that there can be anything inside the brackets before the number (or after, if you want). The pattern `r'\(.*(\d{4}).*\)'` does this.

#### Libraries

You want to import re, and pandas.

#### Working code

Here is the code with the above modifications made:

```
def amend_vals(value):
    pattern = r'\(.*(\d{4}).*\)'
    match = re.search(pattern, value)
    if match:
        year = match.group(1)
        return re.sub(pattern, '(discont. ' + year + ')', value)
    else:
        return value
```